# Ruby, Map, Object attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an object that looks like the below:

```
class Report
  attr_accessor :weekly_stats, :report_times

  def initialize
    @weekly_stats = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k]={}}
    @report_times = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k]={}}
    values = []
  end
end
```

I want to loop through the weekly_stats and report_times and upcase each key and assign it its value.

Right now I have this:

```
report.weekly_stats.map do |attribute_name, value|
  report.values <<
 {
    :name => attribute_name.upcase,
    :content => value ||= "Not Currently Available"
  }
end
report.report_times.map do |attribute_name, value|
  report.values <<
  {
    :name => attribute_name.upcase,
    :content => format_date(value)
  }
end
report.values
```

Is there a way I could map both the weekly stats and report times in one loop?

Thanks

Comment: does weekly_stats has same attribute_names as report_times has?

Comment: no it doesnt, sample object would be @weekly_stats={"total_transactions => 2}, @report_times={"start_of_week"=>Fri, 15 Mar 2013 00:00:00 EST -05:00, "end_of_week"=>Thu, 21 Mar 2013 23:59:59 EST -05:00}

Comment: You are limited by the fact you are processing values differently for each hash, and have no way to flag how to do this other than the name of the containing instance variable.

Comment: I would find a way to do this on insert, much cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(@report_times.keys + @weekly_stats.keys).map do |attribute_name|
  {
    :name => attribute_name.upcase,
    :content => @report_times[attribute_name] ? format_date(@report_times[attribute_name]) : @weekly_stats[attribute_name] || "Not Currently Available"
  }
end
```

Comment: assuming report_times and weekly_stats has no common keys

Answer (score 2):

If you are guaranteed nil or empty string in `weekly_stats`, and a date object in `report_times`, then you could use this information to work through a merged hash:

```
merged = report.report_times.merge( report.weekly_stats )

report.values = merged.map do |attribute_name, value|
 {
    :name => attribute_name.upcase,
    :content => value.is_a?(Date) ? format_date(value) : ( value || "Not Currently Available")
  }
end
```

Comment: Note this also suffers from problems with identical keys